# Single Table Inheritance with Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, sti

I have model User and model Recruiter. Currently, these are two separate tables, but I want to make them one.

Current:

- User: id, username, password, name
- Recruiter: id, user_id

Ideal:

- User: id, username, password, role (recruiter, admin)

I understand the basics of STI. What I'm wondering is, when I perform methods on the **new** Recruiter controller (that inherits from User) how do I make sure all my methods are calling on users that are only a recruiter? Thus, queries along the lines of...  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 'recruiter'` for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is something rails takes care of for you, out of the box. You do not have to manually query on a particular type of user, just query on the right model.

I must also mention that by default rails assumes that your **sti_column** is called `type`, but can be overridden to `role` easily.

Comment: As much as I want to hate how explicit rails is, stuff like this makes it super wicked. Have a green checkmark! Thanks Puneet!

Answer (score 1):

Let's admit you have your 2 classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Recruiter < User
end
```

Rails will automagically add a **type** column in the **users** table so that in your controller, if you do something like this:

```
class RecruitersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @recruiters = Recruiter.all
  end
end
```

Rails will automatically  fetch the records with *type = 'Recruiter'* and you don't even have to set this manually. If you do:

```
Recruiter.new(name: 'John').save
```

A new User will be created in database with the field **type** set to **'Recruiter'**.

Answer (score 1):

you would define your models something like this:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
 end

 class Recruiter < User
 ...
   def initialize
     # ... special initialization for recruiters / you could put it here
     super
   end
 ...
 end
```

and to create a new recruiter, you would do this:

```
 Recruiter.create(:name => "John Smith")
```

and because of the `type` attribute in the STI user table (set to 'Recruiter'), the record will be for a recruiter.

You could put the special initialization for the STI models either in the model's initializer, or in a before filter with a if-cascade checking the type.
An initializer is probably much cleaner.

Comment: Rails is so cool it boggles my mind. This helped too -- I wish I could award you a greenie.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried has_one association?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one